# Firefox: Wikipedia MathML equations have too much space above and below

Tags: firefox, 15.10, vector-drawings

I recently switched from Windows to Ubuntu and I migrated my Firefox User profile. I have set my Wikipedia profile under Preferences → Appearance to show Math with MathML. Under Windows I didn't experience any problems but under Ubuntu there is too much space above and below equations. See [this example page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_current), here's how it looks:
[image: screenshot]

Any Ideas on how to fix this?
I am also interested in other solutions that display Wikipedia equations as vector graphics.

Using Ubuntu 15.10 and Firefox 43.0.

Comment: It looks quite good to my taste. Could it be that on Windows, there is too little space above and below equations?

Comment: @mikewhatever the problems is that there is double that space between the lines of multi-line Math. And it's too much space anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in the Latin Modern Math version distributed by Ubuntu. See

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lmodern/+bug/1502701
https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T122400

A workaround mentioned on launchpad* is as follows:

> 1. Download the latest version of the Latin Modern Math font from
>      http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/lm-math/download/index_html.
> 2. Unpack the zip file. It contains documentation and a file `latinmodern-math.otf`.
> 3. Copy `latinmodern-math.otf` to `~/.fonts` (which you must create if it doesn't exist).
> 4. Restart Firefox.

** see post #3, by Jérôme Kunegis*

Comment: any idea on how to fix this (change the font...?)

Comment: Install the latest upstream version: http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/lm-math

Comment: Or you can just delete the buggy font from `/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/lm-math/` and install the new version there.